# get a distinct count based on a case condition

Tags: sql

I had a problem that I am not able to solve in one query. I want to find all distinct user_ids that  satisfy policy = 'disable' and multiply them by 9. Is it possible to do in one query? I am  struggling to find such a query.

```
txn_week,
SUM(CASE WHEN policy = 'disable' AND COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) THEN 9 ELSE 0 END) as disabled_accounts
from table
group by txn_week
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
     count(distinct CASE WHEN policy = 'disable' then user_id end) *9 as disabled_accounts
from table
group by txn_week;
```